# How to have a background color of an image link fade to another color?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I actually was able to acheive this on my blog: roseannebarr.tumblr.com
But it only does it for the first one... Any ideas why?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#block").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800);
            },function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#6cb4e2" }, 800);
            });

     });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have an `id` repeated in HTML on the same page, it's not valid and you'll see problems *exactly* like this.  Instead for multiple elements with the same styling and/o behavior, use a class like `class="block"` on your elements, and a matching [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".block").hover(function() {
     $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#a7bf51"}, 800);
   },function() {
     $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#6cb4e2" }, 800);
   });
 });
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @jAndy - sure it does "it only does it for the first one"...that's **exactly** what happens when an ID is repeated.  If you look in the source of the page he posted the URL to, you'll see `id="block"` is repeated many times.

Comment: Well also, the only reason the web page actually functions is BECAUSE i used IDs. If I switch to classes, it completely destroys it and I'm not going to recreate an entire web page that works perfectly in all browsers (with the xception of a small problem in firefox) so it can be "correct". I mean no offense, but I'm tired and just want to finish it. :(

Comment: @Earl - You can't use an ID repeated like this...that's the issue here, there's not really a work around for this invalid HTML, `document.getElementById()` returns a *single* element, and that's what jQuery is using when you call `$("#block")`.

Comment: @Nick: Kudos, I guessed he was missing to use the UI.

Comment: Ugh that sucks so bad because I made the web page pop ups BECAUSE somebody gave me the code on here. I guess I'll forget the animation unless somebody can tell me how to re create the same page using valid HTML.